# how to balance a matrix by proportional adjustment of rows and columns

Tags: matrix, code-request, code-review

Given a matrix:

```
ClearAll[mat, refR, refC];
mat = {
   {21.2, 29, 19.9},
   {9, 48.8, 22.4},
   {49.8, 62.2, 7.8}
    };
```

I want to adjust the elements of `mat` to construct a new matrix satisfying the following row `refR` and column `refC` sums:

```
refR = {75, 82, 125};
refC = {87, 150, 45};
```

At 1st stage I adjust the rows by the following code:

```
mat1 = Table[(mat[[i, j]]/Total[mat, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i,3}, {j, 3}];
```

Then adjust the columns by:

```
mat2 = Table[(mat1[[j, i]]/Total[mat1][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}];
```

Thereafter, I repeatedly carry out row and column adjustments:

```
mat3 = Table[(mat2[[i, j]]/Total[mat2, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
mat4 = Table[  (mat3[[j, i]]/Total[mat3][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}];
mat5 = Table[  (mat4[[i, j]]/Total[mat4, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
mat6 = Table[  (mat5[[j, i]]/Total[mat5][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}];
mat7 = Table[  (mat6[[i, j]]/Total[mat6, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
mat8 = Table[  (mat7[[j, i]]/Total[mat7][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}];
mat9 = Table[  (mat8[[i, j]]/Total[mat8, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
mat10 = Table[  (mat9[[j, i]]/Total[mat9][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}];
mat11 = Table[  (mat10[[i, j]]/Total[mat10, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
mat12 = Table[  (mat11[[j, i]]/Total[mat11][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}];
mat13 = Table[  (mat12[[i, j]]/Total[mat12, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
mat14 = Table[  (mat13[[j, i]]/Total[mat13][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}];
```

until the following conditions hold TRUE:

```
Total[mat14, {2}] == refR
Total[mat14] == refC
```

There must be a clever way of doing these iterations to balance the matrix `mat` to the new reference row and column sums as above.

Can a single function be created? Such as

```
matrixBalance[m_Matrix, refR_, refC_, mp_]:=
```

where `m_Matrix` is the original unbalanced matrix, `refR` is the reference vector of row totals, `refC` is the reference vector of column totals, and `mp` is the number of matrix iterations. The outcome of this function should be the final balanced matrix satisfying `refR` and `refC`. In economics, this repeated iteration method is called RAS method and is widely used in the balancing of Input-Output matrix and/or Social Accounting Matrix.

Any improvement on the above code is appreciated...

Comment: What if no matrix has the given row sums and column sums? The example here is a case in point. What result is expected? Some form of optimization?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: As I indicated below, there is a lower bound for the resulting matrix elements. They should be all non-negative and  `Total[refR]=Total[refC]`.

Comment: with your inputs `refR` and `refC` the condition `Total[refR]=Total[refC]` is not satisfied (and your iterative scheme oscillates indefinitely). Is it acceptable to pre-process `refR` and `refC` to ensure  `Total[refR]=Total[refC]`?

Comment: @kglr: Yes, you are right that the example in my question above has a typo, `refC[[1]]=87` is the correct input. It is necessary to pre-process the condition `Total[refR] = Total[refC]`. The type of matrices I have has non-negative elements (i.e., input coefficients of a production function), meaning (1) if the original matrix element is positive, the resulting number cannot be `0` and must be positive but maybe very small, (2) if the original matrix element is equal to `zero`, it has to remain as `zero`. Zero elements cannot be positive after iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inputs:**

```
mat = {{21.2, 29, 19.9}, {9, 48.8, 22.4}, {49.8, 62.2, 7.8}};
refR = {75, 82, 125};
refC = {87, 150, 45};
```

**Iteration steps:**

```
mnt = Map[Normalize[#, Total] &];

fr = refR  mnt @ # &;

fc = Transpose[refC  mnt @ Transpose @ #] &;

frc = fc @* fr;
```

**Stopping criteria:**

```
imbalance = Norm[Join[refC, refR] - Join[Total@#, Total[#, {2}]]] &;

tolerance = 10^-5;

unbalancedQ = imbalance[#] > tolerance &;

maxIterations = 10^3;
```

**Initialize:**

```
iter = 1;

msoln = N @ mat;
```

**Iterate** while current `imbalance` exceeds `tolerance` and `iter` is below `maxiterations`:

```
While[iter++ <= maxIterations && unbalancedQ[msoln = frc @ msoln]]
```

**Display results:**

```
gridDisplay[mat, refR, refC, msoln, "M", iter]
```

[image]

**Helper functions for display:**

```
augM = Grid[Join[Join[#, List /@  Total[#, {2}], 2], {Total@#}], 
    Dividers -> {{-2 -> Red}, {-2 -> Red}}] &;

gridDisplay = Grid[{{"\nmat", "refR\nrefC", 
      "\n" <> ToString[Superscript[#5, #6], StandardForm],  
      "\nimbalance", "\niterations"}, 
   {augM @ #, Column[{#2, #3}], augM @ #4, imbalance @ #4, iter}}, 
   Dividers -> All] &;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine with the small matrix but when I try it with `SeedRandom[123];
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {9, 9}];
refR = {150, 120, 140, 160, 140, 160, 150, 170, 150};
refC = {140, 170, 150, 140, 110, 150, 160, 150, 170};` it is very very slow. Is there anyway to speed it up?

Comment: I did not understand what `"M"` refers to in `gridDisplay[mat, refR, refC, msoln, "M", iter]`. It seems to refer to `imbalance`, but why `"M"`?

Comment: I got it, sorry...it is the notation for the final matrix with the iteration number as superscript.

Comment: @TugrulTemel,  re "anyway to speed it up", warp `mat` with `N` (ie use `mat = N@ mat`). Re `M^8` it is meant to be the label for the for the form of the initital matrix at 8th iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now it is very very quick...

Comment: The above code works if I construct a matrix `mat` manually; however, if I use the followings: `SeedRandom[123]; n=100;
mat = RandomReal[100, {n, n}]*RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
refC = Total[mat]*RandomReal[{1, 1.25}, {n, n}];
refR = refC;`, the computations do not converge. This is really a puzzle for me. Why do you think so?

Comment: On the contrary, this is working: `SeedRandom[12];
scenario = 
  Table[1 + beta[i], {i, 100}] /. {beta[2] -> 0.25, beta[8] -> 0.5, 
     beta[17] -> 0.4, beta[27] -> 0.1} /. 
   Table[beta[i] -> 0, {i, 100}];
mm = 10;
tmp = SparseArray[{}, {mm, mm}, 1];
mat = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, Dimensions[tmp] {mm, mm}] -> {tmp}}, 
    Dimensions[tmp] {mm, mm}]*RandomReal[50000, {100, 100}];
refC = Total[mat]*scenario;
refR = refC;` Sorry for this very late comment.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, `refR` and `refC` should be vectors; in the example with `refC = Total[mat]*RandomReal[{1, 1.25}, {n, n}]; refR = refC;` they are 100 X 100 matrices.

Comment: It was a mistake on my side. However, here is the correct version with a vector, which is still not working. `scenario = 
  Table[1 + beta[i], {i, n}] /. {beta[2] -> 0, beta[8] -> 0, 
     beta[17] -> 0, beta[27] -> 0} /. Table[beta[i] -> 0, {i, n}]; (* a vector*)
mat = SetPrecision[N[adjustedSAM[sam18]], 5];  (* a matrix I import from Excel and has no problem with it because it works if I set all beta[i]=0. It does not work if I set some beta[i] !=0)
refC = Total[mat]*scenario;
refR = refC;` You do not have to explain the details if it takes too much of your time.

Answer (score 5):

A starting point.

```
Clear[refR,refC,m,f,g];
refR = {x1, x2, x3};
refC = {y1, y2, y3};
m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3}];
f = Times[#, refR] &@*Map[Normalize[#, Total] &];
g = Transpose[#] &@Times[#, refC] &@*Map[Normalize[#, Total] &]@
    Transpose[#] &;
```

```
f@m == Table[(m[[i, j]]/Total[m, {2}][[i]])*refR[[i]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
g@m == Table[(m[[j, i]]/Total[m][[i]])*refC[[i]], {j, 3}, {i, 3}]
```

> `True`.

> `True`.

```
mat = {{21.2, 29, 19.9}, {9, 48.8, 22.4}, {49.8, 62.2, 7.8}};
refR = {75, 82, 125};
refC = {85, 150, 45};
ComposeList[{f, g, f, g, f, g, f, g, f, g, f, g, f, g}, mat]
%== {mat, mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, mat5, mat6, mat7, mat8, mat9, mat10, 
  mat11, mat12, mat13, mat14}
```

> `True`.

**Edit**

Since `refC = {87, 150, 45};` now the above code work.

```
mat = {{21.2, 29, 19.9}, {9, 48.8, 22.4}, {49.8, 62.2, 7.8}};
refR = {75, 82, 125};
refC = {87, 150, 45};
result=FixedPoint[g@*f, mat]
Total[result, {2}] == refR
Total[result] == refC
```

> `{{24.1287, 32.4684, 18.4029}, {9.81314, 52.342, 19.8448}, {53.0581,  65.1896, 6.75229}}`

> `True`.

> `True`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Code. It works fine. It is quite slow when matrix dimension goes over 5. Even with my very powerful computer, `ComposeList` is extremely slow and in fact I cannot get a solution because it runs for ever. Is there a way to speed up the operations?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It works just fine with the given example. For large matrices, it runs for ever with no result.

Comment: When I wrap `mat` with `N` (suggested by kglr), your code is also very quickly converging. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: The code you developed above is very very slow. Is there a way to speed it up? I am running a system with 75 by 75, and the code continuously runs with no output. It should not be that way, I. suppose.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an optimization problem. One thing  that can be minimized is the sum-of-squares-of-discrepancies error.

```
matrixBalance[m_, refR_, refC_] /; 
  Dimensions[m] === {Length[refR], Length[refC]} := Module[
  {dims = Dimensions[m], x, mplus, eqC, eqR, vals, min, soln},
  mplus = Array[x, dims];
  eqC = Total[mplus + m] - refC;
  eqR = Total[mplus + m, {2}] - refR;
  vals = Join[eqR, eqC];
  {min, soln} = FindMinimum[vals . vals, Flatten[mplus]];
  {min, m + mplus /. soln}
  ]
```

This example:

```
mat = {{21.2, 29, 19.9}, {9, 48.8, 22.4}, {49.8, 62.2, 7.8}};
refR = {75, 82, 125};
refC = {85, 150, 45};
mb = matrixBalance[mat, refR, refC]

(* Out[187]= {0.666667, {{23.2889, 32.7556, 18.6222}, {10.0556, 51.5222, 
   20.0889}, {51.9889, 66.0556, 6.62222}}} *)
```

This is in fact close to `mat14` from the question. But that has sos error of 1.40707 instead of 2/3.

--- edit ---

If there are constraints on the result e.g. nonnegativity of matrix elements (as noted in a comment), one can use this optimization instead.

```
{min, soln} = 
  FindMinimum[{vals . vals, Thread[Flatten[mplus + m] >= 0]}, 
   Flatten[mplus]];
```

In general, just place the constraints in a list after the objective function. Since these particular constraints are linear, `FindMinimum` will likely use quadratic programming under the hood so it should still be fairly efficient. And one can minimize the 1-norm instead of Euclidean, and then cast it as a linear program. This is probably overkill but could matter when dimensions are large.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thanks for this efficient code. It works like charm. In fact, when I introduce a necessary condition, which is `Total[refR]==Total[refC]`, then I get `{1.65192*10^-19, {{23.8444, 32.6444, 18.5111}, {10.6111, 51.4111, 
   19.9778}, {52.5444, 65.9444, 6.51111}}}` a very tiny error.

Comment: When I tried it for a matrix (22,22), some of the resulting matrix entries become negative, which are not acceptable in the type of problems I address. It means that a condition needs to be imposed on the final solution matrix that all entries are non-negative. Is it possible to add this condition to your code?

Comment: See edit for imposing constraints.