# How to set the precision for the entire notebook

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I want to do various computations conditional on a given precision for the entire notebook. I use the following code:

```
Block[{$MaxPrecision = 3},
 SetPrecision[{"various computations"},3]
]
```

All of the computations are placed in `SetPrecision[{...},3]`. The output from the above code seems fine but when I use `Enter` key then the numbers look as if no precision is applied.

Furthermore, how can I override `Default Precision` with `$MaxPrecision=3`?

Comment: Could you set the precision of your numerical inputs instead? For instance, if you set ```initialVariable = 1`3``` then any calculations that involve that value will automatically keep track of the appropriate precision.

Comment: @MarcoB: I have a large matrix `mat` of numbers. This matrix is used in the computation of variables in the successive steps in the code. How do I set the precision of the matrix `mat`?

Comment: @MarcoB: There must be an easy way to set the precision for the entire notebook. I need to do that because there are many other computations done in the same notebook.

Comment: `SetPrecision[mat, 3]` would do it. I don't believe there is a "global precision setting" in the sense you intend. Can you explain a bit more why you think you need it? If you want speed, then machine-precision is your best bet anyway,

Comment: @MarcoB: A global precision for a notebook is necessary to set a desired level of precision for many different computation carried out within that notebook. It will be inconvenient, if not inefficient, to set the precision for single computation.

Comment: @MarcoB: My overall goal is to limit the precision to force a solution to my computation problem, otherwise, there is no solution to the problem. If possible, I want to use `Tolerance` also.

Comment: @MarcoB: Does `$MaxPrecision = 5` as the first line in the notebook set the precision to 5 for the entire notebook?

Comment: It limits the maximum number of digits of precision used in arbitrary-precision numbers, so that may approximate what you want, but there are some significant caveats. For one, machine-precision calculations are not affected, because they do not use the arbitrary-precision machinery. Secondly, and perhaps more importantly, the docs say that "when `$MaxPrecision` is set, some computations may not get correct results" because a higher precision than requested would be required to obtain the correct result. The latter drawback would be a show-stopper to me.

Comment: Could you share a specific calculation that you would like to run at limited precision, and the output you would like to obtain from it?

Comment: @MarcoB: I like to share it but it is too much for this site. Small examples do not make sense because I have no problem with small size problems. Originally, I have (74, 74) matrix and a chunk of computations. Here is the link for the code I am trying to replicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288139/60365>. In this code, I have a problem with matrix `mat`.